# Word to describe sounds from a one-year old child

Tags: single-word-requests

Which word can I use to describe random nonsense sounds like 'aaaa', 'papa' etc. from a child who still cannot speak.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two words are generally used to describe baby talk (the definitions are from Chambers):

- *Prattle* — "(of a young child) to utter baby-talk"
- *Babble* — "to speak like a baby"

Comment: +1 You could include links to corresponding entries from Chambers online as well, for completeness.

Comment: Though "prattle" is usually used to mean "chatter" and isn't common as a technical term, I don't think.

Answer (score 10):

For sounds like 'aaaa,' I would say *cooing*.

Sounds like 'mama,' I would say *babbling*.

I would probably avoid *prattling* because it is also used to mean annoying, incessant talking.

Comment: Agree that "prattle" tends to be used in reference to chatty adults.

Answer (score 3):

*Babble* fits your description. It can be used as a noun or verb.

Comment: @RegDwight - thanks for changing the backticks for italics. Just for future reference, is there a standard to follow as far as which one to use when?

Answer (score 3):

According to the *Facts on File Descriptionary* (2000), one apt term for such sounds is *lallation*:

> **lallation** any noise or utterance typical of a baby.

*Merriam-Webster's Third New International Dictionary* (1986) generally confirms this meaning:

> **lallation** *n* **1 :** infantile utterance whether in infants or in older speakers (as by retardation or mimicry) **2 :** a defective articulation of the letter *l*, the substitution of \l\ for another sound, or the substitution of another sound for \l\—compare LAMBDACISM

Interestingly, the *Oxford English Dictionary, Compact Edition* (1971) asserts that the "childish utterance" meaning of *lallation* is obsolete, and that the only current meaning is this:

> An imperfect pronunciation of *r*, by which the sound of that letter is confused with that of *l*; lambdacism.

For the record, the Third International Dictionary defines *lambdacism* as follows:

> **lambdacism** *n* **1 :** excessive use of the letter *l* or the sound \l\ (as in alliteration) 2 : defective articulation of \l\ or substitution of other sounds for it 3 : substitution of \l\ for another sound [example omitted] —compare LALLATION

Answer (score 1):

If the baby is repeating sounds then it's [echolalia](http://www.onelook.com/?w=echolalia).
Only tangetially related to your question I know, but I like the word.

Comment: interesting. I only knew this word as related to the disorder.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be helpful... because this might be old... but here's something anyway! *Mumble*, *blabber*, and *Lisp* (as in lisped).

Comment: Back in 2012 there wasn't a baby in the White House.