# Term for toddler-mispronounced words

Tags: single-word-requests, speech, phonetics

Is there a single-word equivalent to "child speech"? A term that would convey that a toddler, still learning the language, has mispronounced a word?

Comment: **Baby talk** is the language used by babies when they are just learning to speak, or the way in which some adults speak when they are talking to babies. [[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/baby-talk)] This answers your title query but not the SWR.

Comment: With babies (less than a year old) the terms *cooing* and *babbling* are sometimes used. However from when the child starts to talk there appears no particular way of describing their early speech other than using the adult terms - *speak*, *talk*, *chatter* etc.

Comment: Infantile (pronunciation) is what it's called when someone who can say it the right way mispronounces a word like an infant would.

Comment: WS2's *babble* is probably as close as you'll get with common words; *coo* is specific with respect to tone.  If you want to go to the dark,technical side of speech pathology, you can read about CAS at http://www.asha.org/public/speech/disorders/ChildhoodApraxia/

Comment: Related: [Word to describe sounds from a one-year old child](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/67794/191178)

Comment: There is, I suggest, a kinship between baby talk and the phenomenon of glossolalia (i.e., fabricated and non-meaningful speech). I'm not exactly sure what the connection might be, but infants can fabricate "words" that sound like the real words they are attempting to say. Just a thought.

Answer (score 4):

I believe a common English phrase for this would be "baby talk." I'm unsure if there is a single word for this phenomenon, but the Oxford English Dictionary definition for baby talk matches what you're describing.

"baby talk n. the imperfect speech of a young child; the speech of an adult or older child imitating this, typically used when speaking to young children or pets; (more generally) nonsense."

Comment: If you leave out the space between _baby_ and _talk_, you get an official one-word answer, totally free, with a money-back guarantee, subject to [the usual disclaimers](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/disclaimers.html).